# How can I repair a 6x6 fence post split at the hinge mounted near the edge?

Tags: repair, fence, hinges

Any suggestions on a way to fix a 6x6 fence post that has split at the fasteners to the top hinge of the gate that attaches to it. It's buried in concrete so I'd rather not dig it out to replace it.  I have some 6x4 scrap and I was thinking of cutting a notch out and using some through bolts (w/ maybe some adhesive) and bolt it into place and then reattach the hinge.  I cant find a hinge that will fit the post yet bite further away from the edge? Any other ideas?

[image: post split]

[image: 6x4 scrap]

[image: hinges]

Comment: that is the wrong type of hinge ... find one that ban be bolted in the middle of the post

Comment: Actually, that hinge could've easily been mounted close to center on the post. There's no reason I can see that the pin needs to be between the post and the gate.

Comment: @isherwood but the bolt through the gate is only maybe an inch from the edge of the gate.  Can't shift *that* part too much closer to the post, unless you think the bolt on the end is sufficiently strong.

Comment: It looks like there's room to me. A through-bolt can be fairly close to the edge as there's virtually no lateral force applied. (I would put through-bolts on the other leaf, too.)

Answer (score 3):

Your hinge looks like it might need to be replaced anyway so one with more reach would be ideal.

Otherwise, for something similar, fit a 90 degree steel angle where each hinge screw hole is (so two of them). Use them to bring the splintered piece back where it belongs. Drill an extra hole in each angle for the hinge screw if you can't line up one of the existing holes.

Glue would be a good idea before you pull the wood back together. If the hinge screws want to pull out, stuff the holes with wood glue and toothpicks. Let it dry and try again.

I imagine you could also put the angles over the hinge tabs but assembly might become difficult.

Comment: thanks fof ghe help. Any idea which hinges would have more reach? I don't see anything that would mount any further from the edge.

Comment: @diyer0001 browse your favorite hardware store website for fence hinges. I see several models with screws further away from the hinge pin.

Comment: Can you point to one?  I edited the post to show some of the home depot selection.  There are strap hinges but they wouldn't fit on the post.  The Tee hinges are all pretty close to the edge (maybe your definition of 'edge' or 'close' is different than mine), they all seem to be about 1-2 inches from the hinge which is about the same as the current one.

Comment: I would recommend that you use some sort of weather resistant glue designed for outdoor use. TiteBond™ 3 is one example - there are many others.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the bolts for that hinge so close to the edge of the wood was guaranteed to fail in exactly the manner it did.

If replacing the post is not possible then one possibility is to weld or bolt that hinge to a steel plate about 6" square, then fix the plate to the post with 3 or 4 screws spaced either side of the centre line of the post.

Answer (score 0):

First, the wood looks badly weathered, and the weight of the gate puts heavy strain on it, so a partial fix would likely need to be redone. In fact the part embedded below ground might be in worse shape.

As you state adding a sister would change the dimensions of the gate, requiring hardware change.

That said it could be repaired, e.g., by removing the hardware, liberally applying wood glue and clamping, and then, after it's dried, covering with a reinforcing wrap, such as fiberglass, and adding a fence post cap, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08TVJD28C), to reduce water infiltration.

If feasible, I'd drill and chisel out the old post from the concrete, and set in a new post, *with cap*. The existing hole could be made slightly larger, or the new post shaved at the bottom to fit, with any space filled with [expanding urethane foam](https://www.homedepot.com/s/expanding%20urethane%20post%20set).

Comment: There is no collar rot where the post meets the concrete.  Replacing the post by digging out the concrete is just much more work than I'm willing to put in.  I believe there should be a solution that would last the remaining lifetime of the fence. Thanks for the post cap tip.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with the look of a Simpson bracket, you could glue and clamp the splintered piece of wood back in place.  Once cured, get an angle bracket (or two, depending on length), drill the appropriate holes in it for your hinge screws, and screw the bracket over the corner.  Then screw your hinge back on over the bracket.  You could paint the bracket black to match the hinge if you like.